# Retrieving data from original python file to go to imported python file

Tags: python

What i'm coding requires a python file, called main, importing another python file to run its code entirely before returning to run to main. However the imported python file requires data from the original python file to work properly? is there a way to have parameters or something similar when importing the file? i tried this, but didnt work quite obviously:

```
Dataset="Hello world"
import ExternalFile(Dataset)
```